# Did I find a few (small) errors in the Pradic and Brown 2021 paper that Schroeder-Bernstein implies excluded middle?

Tags: lo.logic, constructive-mathematics

I'm looking at the https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09193 paper (version 2, from 2021) and think it has a few errors. I think I found three small places where the paper needs to be corrected (in the sense that the corrected version is valid - none of the key conclusions are undermined by this).

1. On page 5 it says "Lemma 3.5. Let Q ∈ $2^{N_∞}$ be given. If Q(ω) = 1 and ∀n ∈ N. Q(n) = 1, then ∀p ∈ $2^{N_∞}$ . Q(p) = 1." I believe the second $2^{N_∞}$ should be $N_∞$ (because Q ∈ $2^{N_∞}$, you'd want to evaluate Q at an element of $N_∞$)
2. A few lines down is the statement "Theorem 3.6 ([Esc13, Theorem 3.15]). There is a function ε : $2^{N_∞}$ → $N_∞$ such that for every
   Q ∈ $2^{N_∞}$ , if Q(ε(Q)) = 1, then ∀p ∈ $2^{N_∞}$ . Q(p) = 1.". The last $2^{N_∞}$ should be $N_∞$ for the same reason.
3. At the end of the proof of that theorem, in "Hence
   Q(p) = 1 for every p ∈ $2^N$", $2^N$ should be $N_∞$ again for the same reason.

Perhaps this is a social question - how do I contact an author? - but I also wanted to post here to see whether what I am proposing is right and in case other people are hitting this when trying to read this paper.

P.S. I formalized these proofs at https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/nninfall.html and https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/nninfsel.html in case that helps.

Comment: The preprint lists the authors' institutional affiliations (but not their emails, unfortunately).  The institution website will have homepage for their faculty where you can find their contact info - googling authorname institutionname will usually work.  If what you found are indeed typos (even if only one out of the three is a genuine typo), the authors will probably appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Assuming you have a valid arXiv account (or if you know someone who does), on the arXiv page you can click "view email" of the corresponding author who uploaded the pre-print. That e-mail will most likely be current (as every time you upload/update a pre-print arXiv asks you to update it if necessary). The uploader for the pre-print you mentioned is https://www.swansea.ac.uk/staff/p.r.a.pradic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may interest you that Martín Escardó also formalized the proofs, see [`Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein-gives-EM`](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/TypeTopology/CantorSchroederBernstein.CSB.html#6327) in his [TypeTopology](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/TypeTopology/index.html) library.

Regarding contacting the authors, I am pretty sure this [Pierre Pradic](https://www.swansea.ac.uk/staff/p.r.a.pradic/) is the right one. Chad has always made it hard to be tracked down. If you search the [coq-club](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/info/coq-club) mailing list archives from 2011 or so, you'll find his email address.

Comment: Oh nice. I figured I probably wasn't the first to formalize Schroeder-Bernstein implies excluded middle, but I was only aware of the Escardó paper on omniscience of NN_infinity, not his formalization linked above.

Comment: I was able to email Pierre Pradic and there is now a version 3 of the paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09193 (published 15 Aug 2022) with the corrections. Thanks for all the help.